# Глупые вопросы новичка

Tags: python-3.x

Я новичок. Хочу научиться писать на Python.

Читаю Самерфилда, прочел 60 страниц и подошел к первым примерам и упражнениям и понял, что за прочтение этих 60 страниц не могу решить нормально не одну программу.

Даже эту! Объясните как правильно ее написать?

[image: Нужно составить сгенерировать текст из списков]

Comment: Вопрос должен быть более конкретным, чтобы на него ответили что-нибудь толковое; а в такой постановке он только спровоцирует агрессию...

Comment: думаю, стоит ещё раз прочесть всё с самого начала, только вдумчиво и с пониманием

Comment: @DukeSpontaneous, ну, вообще-то, такой вопрос должен спровоцировать более или менее конструктивное обсуждение литературы для обучения ... (но, не на этом сайте)

Comment: питон, помню кинул после первого десятка страниц. прывык к `java`, поэтому его синтаксис показался слишком нечитабельным

Comment: "даже эта" задача слишком неудачная. подача неудачная. А так...читать первый раз нужно первый раз пропуская неясные места и понимая ясные - так вы отоформатируете и подготовите мозг. При втором проходе выполнять даже базовый код синтаксиса языка, то есть простейшие инструкции - без выполнения вы забудете. Мозг помнит только то, что использует.

Comment: @DukeSpontaneous типичная "проблема новичка". Мозг "не знает с чего начать и что делать". Я в таких случаях просто читаю чужой код чтобы мозг запомнил "как в этом языке делается это". И автору надо просто глянуть листинг решения, чтобы мозг "привык". Потому и ответил. А была бы задача олимпиадная - тоже поставил бы минус.

Comment: 1- старайтесь текст как текст в вопрос добавлять, а не в виде картинки (если не знаете как скопировать текст из PDF на вашей системе, то задайте отдельный вопрос специально об этом) 2- полное задание без разбора и "не понимаю, объясните" это плохой вопрос для Stack Overflow. Он наврядли поможет кому-то ещё: люди с той же проблемой не смогут его найти ("глупые вопросы"—это слишком абстрактно, текст внутри картинки не ищет). Постарайтесь из задачи, которая требует выполнить несколько шагов, выполнить те шаги, которые вы понимаете и задать вопрос только об одном шаге, который вызывает трудности.

Answer (score 2):

Задача действительно неудачная, как на мой взгляд. И ее подача только запутывает. "выполните 5 циклов" - почему 5??? непонятно. Для четверостишия требуется 4. И вообще 1 цикл и 4 итерации.
А вообще от вас хотят примерно такого.

```
import random

articles = ['the', 'a']
nouns = ['cat', 'dog', 'man', 'woman']
verbs = ['sang', 'ran', 'jumped']
adverbs = ['loudly', 'queitly', 'well', 'badly']

for _ in range(4):
  article = random.choice(articles)
  noun = random.choice(nouns)
  verb = random.choice(verbs)
  adverb = random.choice(adverbs)

  sentype = random.randint(0, 1)
  if sentype == 0:
      sentense = "{} {} {} {}".format(article, noun, verb, adverb)
  else:
      sentense = "{} {} {}".format(article, noun, verb )

  print(sentense)
```